# Why is React resetting/re-rendering form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have the following form:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {apiUpdateUser} from '../../redux/actions/user';

class EditUser extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  };

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.apiUpdateUser('/users_api/users/edit-user', this.state, true);
  };

  onChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
  };

  render() {
    const btnText = 'Submit'
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Edit My Details</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="inputEmail" className="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input 
              type="email" 
              name="username" 
              id="inputEmail" 
              placeholder="Email address" 
              onChange={this.onChange} 
              required 
              autoFocus 
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            <label htmlFor="inputName" className="sr-only">Name</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="name" 
              id="inputName" 
              placeholder="Users First Name" 
              onChange={this.onChange}  
              autoFocus 
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            <label htmlFor="pw-new" className="sr-only">New Password</label>
            <input 
            type="password" 
            name="passwordNew" 
            id="pw-new"  
            placeholder="Password" 
            onChange={this.onChange} 
          />
          </div>

          <div>
            <label htmlFor="pw-confirm" className="sr-only">Password Confirmation</label>
            <input 
            type="password" 
            name="passwordConfirm" 
            id="pw-confirm"  
            placeholder="Password Confirmation" 
            onChange={this.onChange} 
          />
          </div>

          <div>
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">Current Password</label>
            <input 
            type="password" 
            name="password" 
            id="password"  
            placeholder="Current Password" 
            onChange={this.onChange} 
            required 
          />
          </div>

          <button type="submit" disabled={this.props.status === 'updating...'}>{btnText}</button>
        </form>
        <div>{this.props.status}</div>
      </div>
    )
  };
};



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    status: state.user.status
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({apiUpdateUser}, dispatch);
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(EditUser);
```

Once submitted, the following code ( `return {...state, status: action.msg}`) is called inside the api request by `dispatch` to update the `state` which updates the div that shows the error message. If i just return unmodified `state` here, the form does not re-render as expected. What is loosing me is why the entire component is re-rendering and not just the div with `this.props.status`.

What i'm trying to do is prevent the component/form from re-rendering when there is an error and `status` is updated. Since `status` is part of `state`, when the `status` part of `state` changes in the reducer, its re-rendering the whole `form` instead of just the `status div`.

I tried adding unique `key` to the `form` and to the `status div`. I tried making the `status div` a separate component and passing `status` as `props`. I tried `shouldComponentUpdate` and the only thing i've been able to do to prevent this is to not update the status in state.

How can i prevent the form from re-rendering when updating state? Am i using redux-thunk and react wrong?

**Note** as a work around, i added `this.state = {status: ''}` to the constructor, changed `apiUpdateUser` to a promise and removed it from `mapDispatchToProps`. On promise resolve I update the status on the page and if no errors, i call a action to update the user since re-rendering is ok if no errors. I'm just not sure why my original method is not working as expected.

Comment: What's the problem? By mapping status to props the component will update when the value of status changes. React's diffing algorithm then determines, in a performant way, which elements need to be updated and which can stay the same. If you wanted you could create a status component and map state to props within that component instead of the form.

Comment: "If you wanted you could create a status component and map state to props within that component instead of the form", i just did something similar while testing different methods. The 'problem' is when calling setState inside a component, react only updates the affected divs as expected. But updating state from redux reducer always forces the entire component to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire `EditUser` component subscribes to a Redux state, when the state change, the entire component will be re-rendered. That's how connected component works. If you don't want the entire form to be re-rendered, you can just put the submit button and the div below the button in one component and make the component a connected component that subscribes to the status state, you don't use the state in other places anyway.